# Tool to validate regex

Tags: java, regex

My goal is to validate regex for wildcard in domain addresses;

I've tried to do it through java.util.regex.Pattern, but some cases confuse me.
Can someone explain, why it considered as valid pattern:

```
Pattern.compile("h]cat")
```

And this one as not valid:

```
Pattern.compile("h[cat")
```

Comment: Because it's interpreted from left to right. `[` opens a character class. And it's not closed.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to validate regular expressions ? Are you asking why you must escape the `[` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `h]cat` in this string `]` means a literal `]` symbol.
- `h[cat` in this string, a character class is started `[` but without termination. So it's not valid. `[` considered as start of char class.

Answer (score 2):

It's a syntax thing. `{` and `}` can exist on themselves as literal, and so does `]` when it's alone. An unclosed `[` however, is syntax error.